# how to code html tags and special characters in xml file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a `<text>` tag in my xml file where I'm putting content from article from database. It contains html tags.
Sample content looks like this

```
lt;p class="align-justify"&gt;1. Zagadnienia wst&#x119;pne&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
&lt;p class="align-justify"&gt;2. Wyja&#x15B;nienia do wzoru&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
```

Same problem is with national special characters :/

It looks like this in my file. Is this ok? Can't I save them as tags?

Answer (score 0):

You could emmbed the html code betwwen the de CDATA tag. That will prevent your XML processor from scaping HTML especial characters. See [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) for further details.